# Mac OS 10.9's (Mavericks) deinstalled Django

Tags: python, django, osx-mavericks

After installing Mac OS 10.9 (Mavericks) the Django version is no longer installed or apparently the system can't find the right paths to make it runs. How can I repair this?

This are the errors I'm getting trying to run Django:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
>>> 


$ python manage.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Comment: did you install django in a virtual enviroment and forgot to activate it ?

Comment: How did you originally install Django?

Comment: well, I installed Django as "The Django Book" says in chapter 2. http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter02.html,
  1. tar xzvf Django-1.4.2.tar.gz
  2. cd Django-*
  3. sudo python setup.py install

Comment: @karthikr no I didn't

Answer (score 2):

Did you install Django into your main Python directory? If so, the version of Python might have been upgraded. This might have wiped your central `site-packages`. If, so, just reinstall Django.

Alternatively, and more advisable, use [virtualenv](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). This will create a separate Python environment (including `site-packages` for each project), preventing this (probably) from happening again in future.

Comment: Thank you! I will check virtualenv out!

Answer (score 0):

Install VirtualEnv Systemwide then setup virtual env

Installing

```
sudo easy_install virtualenv
```

now create project folder and cd into that after that

```
 virtualenv venv
. venv/bin/activate
```

then install django using pip

```
pip install django
```